# «С беседки» или «из беседки» открывается вид?

Tags: предлоги

«С беседки» или «из беседки» открывается вид? Если в беседке, значит, должно быть «с беседки»?

Answer (score 2):

Если залезть на крышу беседки, то с некоторой натяжкой можно будет назвать приемлемым вариант ***"с беседки"***.
Если же находиться **внутри** беседки, то правильно будет ***"из беседки"*** (***"из дома"***, ***"из кареты"*** и т.д.)

Предлог **"с"** употребляется в данном контексте тогда, когда речь идет о какой-то поверхности или территории, а не о замкнутом пространстве: ***"с крыльца"***, ***"со сцены"***, либо о какой-то выделяющейся по высоте точке (например, **"с высокой колокольни"** не обязательно подразумевает, что речь идет о крыше колокольни).

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ, но замечу в комментарии, что автор вопроса просто запутался в мнемоническом правиле **в — из, на — с** (см. его объяснение в вопросе).

Comment: На Кубе - с Кубы, разве не так?

Comment: @flossyU, да, так. В принципе, это соответствует тому, что я написал в ответе: "Предлог "с" употребляется в данном контексте тогда, когда речь идет о какой-то поверхности или территории". Хотя с географическими названиями все намного сложнее и там могут быть варианты. Например, здесь значимым моментом является то, что Куба - остров.